# Cannot read property x of undefined in HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Hi I have the following Canvas application: http://dev.driz.co.uk/canvas/

But it's not rendering anything out. It should be showing a bunch of balls that move around the screen when the user moves the cursor. I think it's just a small bug somewhere because it was working fine in an older version here: http://dev.driz.co.uk/app/

It's taking a while to load as if it's doing something but just snagging somewhere, but the code looks fine to me. After testing in Firebug the following error comes up: 'Cannot read property x of undefined' on several lines mainly around the gradient creation. I have no idea what the problem is :/ It also complains about property color as well. I have tried for a couple of hours to try and fix this, but I'm lost, really need some help.

If anyone can help it'd be much appreciated. Thank you

EDIT: Here is the code:

```
function App()
            {

                var pool    =   document.getElementById('pool');            
                var canvas  =   pool.getContext('2d');
                var cwidth  =   pool.width = document.width;
                var cheight =   pool.height = document.height;
                var ctop    =   pool.offsetTop;
                var cleft   =   pool.offsetLeft;
                var size    =   [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30];

                var numBalls    =   10;

                var i;
                var x;
                var y;

                var mouseX = 0;
                var mouseY = 0;


                // GIVES EACH BALL A RANDOM COLOR

                function rgb()
                { 
                    var color = 'rgb(';

                    for( i=0; i<3; i++)
                    { 
                        color += Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ',';
                    }

                    return color.replace(/\,$/,')');
                }

                // CREATES A BALL

                function CreateBall(x, y, vx, vy, r, s)
                {
                    this.color = rgb();
                    this.x     = x;
                    this.y     = y;
                    this.vX    = vx;
                    this.vY    = vy;
                    this.r     = r;
                    this.size  = s;
                }

                var ball = [], x, y, vx, vy, r, s;

                for ( i = 0; i < numBalls; i++ )
                { 
                    /*x  = Math.random() * cwidth  >> 0;
                    y  = Math.random() * cheight >> 0;
                    vx = Math.random() * 20 - 6;
                    vy = Math.random() * 20 - 6;
                    r  = Math.random() * 30 + 30;*/
                    x = cwidth / 2;
                    y = cheight / 2;
                    vx = Math.random() * 20 - 6;
                    vy = Math.random() * 20 - 6;
                    r = Math.random() * 30 + 30;

                    s  = size[Math.random() * size.length >> 0];

                    // CREATES THE BALLS

                    ball.push( new CreateBall(x, y, vx, vy, r, s)); 
                }

                setInterval(function ()
                {
                    canvas.clearRect(0, 0, cwidth, cheight);

                    for ( i = 0; i < balls.length; i++ )
                    {
                        var gradient = canvas.createRadialGradient(ball[i].x + ball[i].r/4, ball[i].y - ball[i].r/4, ball[i].r/5, ball[i].x, ball[i].y, ball[i].r);
                        gradient.addColorStop(0, '#fff');
                        gradient.addColorStop(.85, ball[i].color);
                        gradient.addColorStop(1, '#222');

                        canvas.fillStyle = gradient;

                        ball[i].vx *= 0.99;
                        ball[i].vy *= 0.99;

                        ball[i].x += ball[i].vx;
                        ball[i].y += ball[i].vy;

                        if ( ball[i].x < ball[i].r || ball[i].x > cwidth - ball[i].r )
                        {
                            ball[i].vx = -ball[i].vx;
                            ball[i].x += ball[i].vx;
                        }

                        if ( ball[i].y < ball[i].r || ball[i].y > cheight - ball[i].r )
                        {
                            ball[i].vy = -ball[i].vy;
                            ball[i].y += ball[i].vy;
                        }

                        canvas.beginPath();

                        canvas.arc ( ball[i].x, ball[i].y, ball[i].r, 0, Math.PI * 2, true );

                        canvas.fill();
                    }
                }, 30);

                // END FOR

                // MOUSE MOVEMENT - BALLS SHOULD MOVE AWAY FROM MOUSE CURSOR

                pool.onmousemove = function ( e )
                {
                    x = e.pageX - cleft;
                    y = e.pageY - ctop;

                    for ( i = 0; i < balls.length; i++ )
                    {
                        if ( Math.abs( x - ball[i].x ) < 20 && Math.abs( y - ball[i].y ) < 20 )
                        {
                            ball[i].vx = ( x - ball[i].x ) / 1;
                            ball[i].vy = ( y - ball[i].y ) / 1;
                        }
                    }
                };

              // END APP

            }
```

Comment: Please show relevant parts of your code; your first link eats all my CPU time...

Comment: The code is within the webpage. I'll add it to the original question.

Comment: I think the var i is at large here ;)

Comment: Am I blind, or is the variable `balls` (used in two for loops) never initialized? Is it supposed to be `ball` perhaps?

Comment: @Frode no you're not, I guess OP might be..., I'm just frustrated seeing same old question by same old OP for the past two weeks( I guess ).. sorry, If this hurts any one

Answer (score 4):

```
function App() {
    var pool = document.getElementById('pool');
    var canvas = pool.getContext('2d');
    var cwidth = pool.width = document.width;
    var cheight = pool.height = document.height;
    var ctop = pool.offsetTop;
    var cleft = pool.offsetLeft;
    var size = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30];
    var numBalls = 3;
    var i;
    var x;
    var y;
    var mouseX = 0;
    var mouseY = 0;

    function rgb() {
        var color = 'rgb(';
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            color += Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ',';
        }
        return color.replace(/\,$/, ')');
    }

    function CreateBall(x, y, vx, vy, r, s) {
        this.color = rgb();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.vx = vx;
        this.vy = vy;
        this.r = r;
        this.size = s;
    }

    var ball = [],
        x, y, vx, vy, r, s;

    for (var i = 0; i < numBalls; i++) {
        x = cwidth / 2;
        y = cheight / 2;
        vx = Math.random() * 20 - 6;
        vy = Math.random() * 20 - 6;
        r = Math.random() * 30 + 30;
        s = size[Math.random() * size.length >> 0];

        ball.push(new CreateBall(x, y, vx, vy, r, s));
    }

    setInterval(function () {
        canvas.clearRect(0, 0, cwidth, cheight);
        for (var i = 0; i < ball.length; i++) {
            var gradient = canvas.createRadialGradient(ball[i].x + ball[i].r / 4, ball[i].y - ball[i].r / 4, ball[i].r / 5, ball[i].x, ball[i].y, ball[i].r);
            gradient.addColorStop(0, '#fff');
            gradient.addColorStop(.85, ball[i].color);
            gradient.addColorStop(1, '#222');

            canvas.fillStyle = gradient;

            ball[i].vx *= 0.99;
            ball[i].vy *= 0.99;

            ball[i].x += ball[i].vx;
            ball[i].y += ball[i].vy;

            if (ball[i].x < ball[i].r || ball[i].x > cwidth - ball[i].r) {
                ball[i].vx = -ball[i].vx;
                ball[i].x += ball[i].vx;
            }

            if (ball[i].y < ball[i].r || ball[i].y > cheight - ball[i].r) {
                ball[i].vy = -ball[i].vy;
                ball[i].y += ball[i].vy;
            }

            canvas.beginPath();
            canvas.arc(ball[i].x, ball[i].y, ball[i].r, 0, Math.PI * 2, 0);
            canvas.fill();
        }
    }, 1000 / 30);

    pool.onmousemove = function (e) {
        x = e.pageX - cleft;
        y = e.pageY - ctop;

        for (var i = 0; i < ball.length; i++) {
            if (Math.abs(x - ball[i].x) < 20 && Math.abs(y - ball[i].y) < 20) {
                ball[i].vx = (x - ball[i].x) / 1;
                ball[i].vy = (y - ball[i].y) / 1;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

I just kicked it's ass **[here](http://jsbin.com/ibice4)**, Do *you* wanna kick it's **ass** too ??

Comment: Awesome thanks very much. I've noticed that when you move the mouse over the balls the ball instead of bouncing away sometimes sticks to the cursor and then you can literally clear the screen by stacking them all together. Any ideas why this is happening? Thanks again, you've been very helpful.

Comment: After thinking about this some more, it would seem it's because the balls do not have collision detection on them so when the mouse moves near them it means the balls just move together rather than away from each other. Or am I wrong? :P

Comment: Here's it is what I had worked on this far http://jsbin.com/oputi/2 . Though it's not perfect(Damn sure, it's not perfect). But I guess it would Give Some thoughts about collision detection.. Anyway I'll look after this code tomorrow. I got to Go College in morning,  it's almost 1Am and I still awake and working on this code(donno why).. Anyway, If you have anything to ask or say, just drop a comment, I'll look after your comments later. But for now I'm sorry for not being helpful :((

Comment: That's looking awesome it's working a lot better than the preview mouse over stuff. Thanks very much. Sorry to have kept you up pal. Thanks again.

Comment: I've actually got what I wanted working now. Thanks for all your help. I've decided against changing the way the moving balls work, as it would be too time consuming and I too have other projects to work on. Thanks again for helping me fix the bugs.